# Finding pdf/cdf of continuous r.v.

Tags: probability

I have a question. I'm given a continuous random variable X with the pdf:

$$f_X(x) = {1\over(1+\pi^2x^2)}\cdot I_{(-\infty, 0)\bigcup(0, \infty)}(x) $$

and asked to find the pdf and cdf of $Y = {1\over X}$. I'm given the hint that $F_Y(-\pi)=1/4$.

I'm having trouble solving for the cdf of the r.v. $Y$.

I get that $F_Y(-\pi)={3\over 4}$ (if $\arctan(-1) = -{\pi\over 4}$) or $-{1\over 4}$  (if $\arctan(-1) = {3\pi\over 4}$), however. This intuitively doesn't make much sense to me, even though I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong with the integration.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In your integral for $F_Y(y)$, why are your limits $\int_{1/y}^\infty$? Seems to me that they should be $\int_{-\infty}^{1/y}$.

Comment: Because of the $P({1\over y} \le X)$ statement. But I think I have  it. Per Andre's suggestion below, you (presumably) flip the inequality, which makes the limits what you suggest (and what works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** We will need to take some care when $y$ is negative, since division then reverses inequalities.

But let's take $y$ positive. What is the probability that $Y\le y$?
This event happens if **either** $X\lt 0$ **or** $X\ge 1/y$.

By symmetry $\Pr(X\lt 0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Your integral expression for $\Pr(X\ge 1/y)$ is correct.

**Added:** For negative $y$, I would suggest not doing a separate calculation, negative numbers are treacherous. If $y$ is negative, then by symmetry the probability that $Y$ is $\le y$ is the same as the probability that $Y\ge |y|$.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I figure (re: your hint), but not sure where to run with that.

Definitely get the symmetry part -- I figure that's why the integral produces the ${1\over 2}$ term. Just not sure about the rest.

(If the arctan() term was positive instead of negative, it'd work out. But that's voodoo math to me unless I can actually compute that.)

Comment: Are you hinting that I should add ${1\over 2}$ to my current expression? That'd work for $arctan(-1)= {3\pi\over 4}$.

Comment: For positive $y$, we have $F_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2}+\int_{1/y}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+\pi^2x^2}$. You integrated correctly, we get $F_Y(y)=1-\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\pi/y)$. This makes sense, it approaches $1$ as $y$ goes to infinity.

Comment: It is not quite a hint, I think it says explicitly you should add $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you! I get your explanation conceptually, just didn't know how I could reconcile that with the math. But this all makes sense.

Comment: The problem was that (for $y\gt 0$) there is more than one way that we can have $Y\le y$: (i) $X$ negative or (ii) $X\ge 1/y$. Your expression for $\Pr(Y\le y)$ only used (ii).